# zclip code copies blank string instead of the contents of text field

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard, zclip

```
<head></head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="description"></input>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a#copy').zclip({
                path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
                copy: $(text#description).text()
            });
        });
    </script>
    <button type="button"><a id='copy' href="#">Copy</a></button>

</body>
```

I think i have it mostly figured out but i don't know why its not working... could you help me out? Instead of zero clipboard i used another library called zclip ( http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/). here's my code : http://jsfiddle.net/3GVX9/1/ thanks in advance! Ps I want to make it so after you click the button it copies the text in the text feild to your clipboard.

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: Still not enough information ... we need a specific error or something other than *not doing what I want it to do*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't syntactically valid: the selector string is not delimited by quotes.

```
copy: $('text#description').text()
```

Your selector is also invalid. It's trying to select a `<text>` element, when you should be selecting an `<input>` element. Since you've got an ID already, there's no reason to write a more-specific selector, anyway.

```
copy: $('#description').text()
```

You also need to get the text to copy when the button is clicked, not when the page loads.

```
copy: function() {
    return $('#description').text();
}
```

But we're dealing with a form input field, so use `.val()` instead of `.text()`:

```
copy: function() {
    return $('#description').val();
}
```

and lastly, you need to set up the fiddle correctly.

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/kqKTG

Comment: Ok I fixed the errors, but it still seems not to copy... the message pops up saying that it copied , but it copies nothing, even when there is text in the feild

Comment: It might be an issue with the external flash file in jsfiddle. I'd recommend setting up a test page that you can fully control.

Comment: I set up a page I can fully control here : http://testificate100.webs.com/index.html . Somehow it still doesn't work, even after i made the changes you told me to. Its still copying a blank string

Comment: Ah, right. `$('#description').text()` is returning an empty string. Use `$('#description').val()` instead. Edited with a working demo.